# Why can't I remote manage a domain-joined Windows 10 computer?

Tags: active-directory, wmi

I have a Active Directory domain of old Windows 7 computers and introduced a new Windows 10 computer.  However, when I right-click the Win10 computer in AD Users & Computers, and select *Manage*, I receive this error:

> Computer (name of computer) cannot be managed.  Verify the network path is correct, the computer is available on the network, and that the appropriate Windows Firewall rules are enabled on the target computer.

The message continues by listing the correct firewall rules to enable.  The problem is that I have already done so via Group Policy for all the computers in the same OU.  As far as I can tell, the Win10 has the same policies applied to it (from running gpresult).  When trying to use the AD Group Policy Results tool, it too fails.  It seems that anything that depends on WMI / DCOM fails, but the services appear to be running fine on the Win10 computer.

I uninstalled anti-virus and disabled Windows Firewall and it still does not work.  If it matters, the Win10 computer has Hyper-V installed, but nothing else that's unusual.

Comment: Does nslookup properly resolve the computer name on your management workstation?

Comment: Yes, the IP returned by nslookup matches the IP of the Win10 machine.

Comment: I've had trouble with WMI on Windows 10 also, and currently our Windows firewalls are disabled. Something that seems random that I think has helped is making sure we have a reverse lookup zone in our AD-integrated DNS servers that is automatically updated by DHCP. Yeah, I know, why would that have anything to do with WMI? I don't know, but right now WMI is working and it started working around the time I made the reverse lookup zone. Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/713643/windows-10-wmi-and-event-viewer-access-denied

Comment: I checked the reverse lookup zone in our AD DNS, and the reverse records match too.  The Windows 10 frustration is building.